# automatically redirect a page with transition using css

Tags: html, css, redirect, transition

When the user view the home page, it will automatically jump to another page after 5s. And I want to add in fading transition when jump to another page. Is there possible to do it using css?

This is the coding i found, but it does not have transition when going to another page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Vert Residence</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<meta name="language" content="en" />
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport' />
<!---<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=vert-residence.html">--->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.maximage.css?v=1.2" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/css/screen.css?v=1.2" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.logo-index {
-webkit-animation-name: example;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-name: example;
animation-duration: 5s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes example {
0% {
opacity: 100;
filter: alpha(opacity=1000);
/* For IE8 and earlier */
}

100% {
opacity: 0.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
/* For IE8 and earlier */
}
}


/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
0% {
opacity: 100;
filter: alpha(opacity=1000);
/* For IE8 and earlier */
}

100% {
    opacity: 0.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
/* For IE8 and earlier */
}
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = "aboutus.html";
}, 2000);
</script>



<div class="logo-index">
    <a href="aboutus.html"><img src="img/logo-index.png"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user wait for 5s it will automatically go to aboutus.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = "/NewPage.aspx";
}, 2000);
```

```css
.wrapper {


  background-color: red;


  width: 100%;


  -webkit-animation-name: example;


  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */


  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;


  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */


  animation-name: example;


  animation-duration: 2s;


}


@-webkit-keyframes example {


  0% {


    opacity: 100;


    filter: alpha(opacity=1000);


    /* For IE8 and earlier */


  }


  100% {


    opacity: 0.0;


    filter: alpha(opacity=0);


    /* For IE8 and earlier */


  }


}


/* Standard syntax */


@keyframes example {


  0% {


    opacity: 100;


    filter: alpha(opacity=1000);


    /* For IE8 and earlier */


  }


  100% {


    opacity: 0.0;


    filter: alpha(opacity=0);


    /* For IE8 and earlier */


  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <div>Home Page</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I not sure what is the problem but after the logo fading, it doesn't automatically jump to another page.

Comment: have you added the page link in that window.location script in my answer i have added some random name.Maybe thats y its not working

Comment: ya, i have added, I had edit the question based on your answer, cn you help me to check which part i done wrong?

Comment: hmm,can you make a fiddle so i can see exactly where it is not working.

Comment: just checked your code on my end it is working fine only getting 404 error after logo fading as i dont have your page "about.html" . but it is getting redirected i think you check with the file location and your path which your giving in the function

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do some adjusting, but you can use a CSS transition. You would have to apply it to your entire page and fade out everything.

```
html {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fgasU/)

Comment: the home page is just the div of the logo after that it will automatically redirect to the information page